# Why control buttons in jcarousel not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I would like use control buttons in **[JsCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)** slider.

In my code i make function for initialization carousel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InitializationJsCarousel(obj){

                var carousel = $(obj).jcarousel({
                    // Core configuration goes here
                });

                $(obj)
                    .on('jcarousel:create jcarousel:reload', function() {
                        var element = $(this),
                            width = element.innerWidth();

                        // This shows 1 item at a time.
                        // Divide `width` to the number of items you want to display,
                        // eg. `width = width / 3` to display 3 items at a time.
                        width = width / 3;
                        element.jcarousel('items').css('width', width + 'px');
                    })
                    .jcarousel({
                        // Core configuration goes here
                    });

                    $('.jcarousel-prev').jcarouselControl({
                        target: '-=1',
                        carousel: carousel
                    });

                    $('.jcarousel-next').jcarouselControl({
                        target: '+=1',
                        carousel: carousel
                    });
            }


$(function(){

...
   InitializationJsCarousel('.jcarousel');
...
});

</script>
```

But as i can see `jcarouselControl` not working. I see console,but errors not found. It problem becouse control buttons not working...

Tell me please why control buttons(`jcarouselControl`) not working and how make that theys work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code working for me.

**First** check that include `jquery.jcarousel-control.js` or `jquery.jcarousel-control.min.js`

**Second** check class name for control element (in your code it `jcarousel-prev`). Check name in js and in html.